# Store new values into JSON

Tags: angularjs, json

I have a `$http.post` that gives me a JSON

```
 $http.post(url, {headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'} })
            .success(function (data) {    
                myService.initialize(data);       
  })
```

The service in which I store the JSON looks like this:

```
app.service('myService', function() {  

    var json = "";    

    this.initialize = function(data) {
        json = data;
    };
});
```

This is the JSON I get:

```
{
  "values": {
    "id": "ABC_123",
    "infotypes": [
      {
        "infotype": "AA1234",
        "syften": [
          {
            "syfteId": 0
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "infotype": "BB4567",
        "syften": [
          {
            "syfteId": 0
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Now, my problem is that I want to add a new infotype "CC6789" with syfteId "0" into the JSON.

I know how to access the different parts in the JSON, to display them in tables using `ng-repeat` and so on. But I don't have a clue how to add something into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanna just do it in-memory, you can add a method to your service that can add some kind of `infotype` object:

```
app.service('myService', function() {  

    var json = "";    

    this.initialize = function(data) {
        json = data;
    };

    this.addInfoType = function(infoType) {
      if(json !== '') {
        json.infotypes.push(infoType);
      } else {
        throw new Error('no json');
      }
    }
});

// somewhere else

myService.addInfoType({
  "infotype": "CC6789",
  "syften": [
     {
       "syfteId": 0
     }
   ]
});
```

Keep in mind, this doesn't do any validation to the data structure you're passing into the service, so you might want to add that.

Comment: I will try this out, and will let you know if it works. Thanks!

Comment: No, `json.infotypes.push(infoType);` does not work.
Any other suggestions?

Comment: Yes! It is working after I added values to
`json.values.infotypes.push(infoType); `